# Unpermitted parameter error whereas parameter specified in params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, many-to-many

I have a `product` model which has a many to many association with a `category` model through join model `category_product`

I have a product/new.html.slim

```
 =simple_form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |t|
        = t.error_notification
        div class="form-group"
          = t.input :name, label: 'Nom',equired: true, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        div class="form-group"
          = t.input :description, label: 'Description', required: true, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        div class="form-group"
          = t.input :price, label: 'Prix', required: true, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        div class="form-group"
          = t.input :weight, label: 'Poids', required: true, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        div class="form-group"
          = t.association :categories, as: :check_boxes, label: "Catégories"
        = t.button :submit, value: "Valider",  class: "btn-success marge-bas"
```

when I submit my form I get the following error :

```
found unpermitted parameter: category_ids
```

though in my ProductController I have permitted category_ids :

```
 def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(
      :category_ids,
      :name,
      :price,
      :description,
      :weight,
      :picture,
      :picture1,
      :picture2,
      :picture3,

    )
  end
```

When I check my `params` `category_ids` is an array of strings

```
"category_ids"=>["1", "2", "5", ""]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting `product_params` to:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, ... :picture3, :category_ids => [])
end
```

Setting the `category_ids` to be an array at the end of your list of permitted params should resolve this error.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this "Unpermitted parameter: category_ids" error when working through the book, "Rails, Up And Running" and adding `category_ids => []` fixed it. Thank you, Zoran!